# Inject service to custom decorator in nestjs

Tags: nestjs, decorator, roles

In my application I have some user roles in db. I need to grab those roles from db and implement a role based authentication.

I'm trying to inject a service(from which I can get the user roles from db) to a custom decorator named "Role" and use this decorator in my controllers to implement the role based authentication. Any idea how I can I inject a service to the custom decorator?

Tried to implement this with guards and decorators and failed

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest a different approach that has worked for me in building Role based authorization in NestJs.

Firstly, add the role to the user object in your auth-guard. Your would do this by querying the database from the access-strategy that you build for yourself. You can see the full example of this [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/passport) in the NestJS docs using Passport.

When this is done, you can use the userRole that you have on your user object to compare the roles with in your roles-guard.

roles.guard.ts:

```
import { Injectable, CanActivate, ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Reflector } from '@nestjs/core';
import { Role } from './role.enum';
import { ROLES_KEY } from './roles.decorator';

@Injectable()
export class RolesGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private reflector: Reflector) {}

  canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): boolean {
    const requiredRoles = this.reflector.getAllAndOverride<Role[]>(ROLES_KEY, [
      context.getHandler(),
      context.getClass(),
    ]);
    if (!requiredRoles) {
      return true;
    }
    const { user } = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    if (!user) {
      return false;
    }
    // This is where the actual checking happens
    return requiredRoles.some((role) => user.userRole === role);
  }
}
```

roles.decorator.ts:

```
export const ROLES_KEY = 'roles';
export const Roles = (...roles: Role[]) => SetMetadata(ROLES_KEY, roles);
```

role.enum.ts

```
export enum Role {
  User = 2,
  Admin = 1,
}
```

your controller:

```
@Controller('admin')
@ApiHeader({
  name: 'Authorization',
  description: 'Bearer...',
})
@Roles(Role.Admin) // Here is your decorator where you specify which user you want to be able to access this. 
@UseGuards(AccessGuard, RolesGuard)
@ApiTags('Admin')
@ApiBearerAuth('accessJWT')
export class AdminController {
  constructor(
    @Inject(YourService)
    private readonly yourService: YourService,
  ) {}
...
```

Hope it helps!